# jQuery datepicker not working properly with a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

First off, the jQuery datepicker works fine with classes when doing a fresh page load.
On my site however I load all the content through Ajax requests.
Initially I gave each date field a unique ID and everything worked fine when loading through ajax.

(Doesnt work through Ajax)

```
<script type='javascript'> jQuery(function() {jQuery('.datepickerclass').datepick({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});});</script>

<input class='Filter datepickerclass' type="text" name="start_date" value=""/>
```

(Works through Ajax)

```
<script type='javascript'> jQuery(function() {jQuery('#start_date').datepick({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});});</script>
<input class='Filter date' type="text" id="start_date" name="start_date" value ="">
```

My best guess is that for some reason datepicker doesn't recheck the page(when using a class) when you reload part of the content and bind to new elements, but I'm not sure how to make it do this?

Comment: Fyi, you can also use `$` instead of writing `jQuery` every time.

Comment: @ThiefMaster unless you are using some other framework (for instance prototype) that also defines `$`

Comment: But since he's using the document.ready shortcut he can use it anyway: `jQuery(function($) { ... });` - the callback gets jQuery passed as the first argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a little try this way. see if the problem goes away (Assuming you are using the jQ UI):

```
$(function(){
    $('.datepickerclass').on('click', function() {
        $(this).datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
    });
});
```

Or have a play along the lines of taking advantage of the live or delegate function. Hope this helps

Comment: Nice, with some slight modifications I got it to work

`$('.datepickerclass').live('click', function() {
        $('.datepickerclass').datepick({dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
        $(this).datepick({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
    });`

Comment: I am glad it helped. You can tick it as the right answer if you like :)

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.datepicker', function() {
        $(this).datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
    });
for jquery 1.10.*

Comment: Why do we have to do this when the JQUERY docs use almost ALL class examples?

Comment: Please note that if you end up here, it's 2015 and the `$.live` method has been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Wes, Changed it to on function.